# Inserting int into random index in arraylist

Tags: arraylist, random, insertion

New to programming, here's my problem. I want to randomly distribute a fixed amount of "ints" (user input) into random indexes in my arraylist. I take to inputs from user, for example:

User types 5: (thats how many indexes I need in my list)

User types 25: (thats the amount that i have to randomly put in the 5 different indexes).

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input N: ");
    int N = sc.nextInt(); // N = 5 from the example above
    System.out.print("Input X:  ");
    int X = sc.nextInt(); // X = 25 from the example above
    ArrayList<Integer> ror = new ArrayList<Integer>(N);

    randomInsert(X, N);

}

public static void randomInsert(int X, ArrayList<Integer> ror) {
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
```

Im thinking that looping through every X and randomly giving it an index in the array "ror" should be easiest? Im kind of stuck here and really appreciate help!

In the end i want to print the array with X randomly distributed in the indexes. Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Put all the computer generated numbers into the ArrayList.
2. Add the user entered numbers to the ArrayList.
3. Convert the ArrayList to an Array.
4. Use Array.shuffle() to randomly shuffle the Array.
5. Print the shuffled Array.

Step 3 is needed because ArrayList does not have a shuffle() method while Array does.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure i understand whether you want to divide the number 25 over a number of indexes in your ArrayList or you want to place the number multiple times over a number of indexes.
But either way, you can use Math.random to generate a random index:
`int random = (int )(Math.random() * a + b);` -> where a is the max number and b is the minimum number you want.

Hope it helps.